# Alert element attribute on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to alert the data-keyid when the fullkey is clicked.

```
$(function() {
    $('.fullkey').click( function (){
        var keyId = $(this).attr('data-keyid');
        alert(keyId);
    });

});

<div class="fullkey">
    <div data-keyid="c-key"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use `.find` to get the child nodes of the parent element. You can filter the set of returned elements using specific selector. `$(this)` is parent selector in this example.

`[data-keyid]` selector could be used to find the child node having attribute as `data-keyid`

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.fullkey').click(function() {
    var keyId = $(this).find('[data-keyid]').attr('data-keyid');
    alert(keyId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fullkey">
  <div data-keyid="c-key">Click Here</div>
</div>

<div class="fullkey">
  <div data-keyid="d-key">Click Here</div>
</div>

<div class="fullkey">
  <div data-keyid="e-key">Click Here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Codepen [Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/XXLVmK)**

click on `div` inside `.fullkey`

you just add  `$('.fullkey div')` on JS.

Here Code:

```
$('.fullkey div').click( function (){
        var keyId = $(this).attr('data-keyid');
        alert(keyId);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
$(this).data("keyid");
```

HTML 5 gives you the ability to add the custom data attributes where each attribute name starts with "data-". JQuery allows to access value of the attribute using the data() function.

Example: . 
The data() function returns the value="c-key".

Comment: please explain you answer to op a little bit.

Comment: HTML 5 gives you the ability to add the custom data attributes where each attribute name starts with "data-". JQuery allows to access value of the attribute using the data() function. Example: <div data-keyid="c-key"></div>. data() function returns the value="c-key"

Comment: I meant edit your answer  and explain it a little for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

when you click on `.fullkey` then `this` has the reference of `.fullkey` but `data-keyid` is attribute of its child element so use `find` to find the element inside it and then get its attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fullkey').click(function (){
        var keyId = $(this).find('div').attr('data-keyid');
        alert(keyId);
    });

});
$(function() {
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fullkey" style="bgcolor:black">
    <div data-keyid="c-key">Click</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/vnjp0ndq/1/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fullkey">Click here
  <div data-keyid="c-key"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  $('.fullkey').click(function() {
    var keyId = $(this).find('div').attr('data-keyid');
    alert(keyId);
  });
});
```